# Tycho & Eclipse-PlatformFilter

Tags: eclipse, maven, tycho

I'm using tycho to automatically build my RCP application (actually, I've adopted the structure reported in [one of the examples](https://github.com/sonatype/sonatype-tycho/tree/master/tycho-demo)). I have to say that it works very well and I'm able to support all the three architectures I need (linux x86, linux x86_64, win32 x86).

Additionally, part of the application requires some native code, which I provide with fragments ([see my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6375112/how-to-insert-platform-specific-code-in-eclipse)). Each fragment is tailored for a particular architecture, hence specify it in the fragment's MANIFEST:

```
Eclipse-PlatformFilter: (& (osgi.os=linux) (osgi.arch=x86_64))
```

However, if I run `mvn install` I obtain:

```
[ERROR] Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: "Problems resolving provisioning plan.": ["tycho.jni.linux 1.0.0.qualifier cannot be installed in this environment because its filter is not applicable."] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.InternalErrorException: Internal error: java.lang.RuntimeException: "Problems resolving provisioning plan.": ["tycho.jni.linux 1.0.0.qualifier cannot be installed in this environment because its filter is not applicable."]
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:168)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: "Problems resolving provisioning plan.": ["tycho.jni.linux 1.0.0.qualifier cannot be installed in this environment because its filter is not applicable."]
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.impl.resolver.ProjectorResolutionStrategy.resolve(ProjectorResolutionStrategy.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.impl.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.resolveProject(P2ResolverImpl.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.impl.resolver.P2ResolverImpl.resolveProject(P2ResolverImpl.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.facade.P2TargetPlatformResolver.doResolvePlatform(P2TargetPlatformResolver.java:389)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.facade.P2TargetPlatformResolver.resolvePlatform(P2TargetPlatformResolver.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.resolver.DefaultTychoDependencyResolver.resolveProject(DefaultTychoDependencyResolver.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.core.maven.TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.afterProjectsRead(TychoMavenLifecycleParticipant.java:91)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:273)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    ... 11 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Problems resolving provisioning plan.
    at org.eclipse.tycho.p2.impl.resolver.ProjectorResolutionStrategy.resolve(ProjectorResolutionStrategy.java:85)
    ... 19 more
```

Note that the **same** project **without** the `Eclipse-PlatformFilter` compiles correctly... what I'm missing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try narrowing down the environments of your fragment's pom.xml to just the one matching the Eclipse-PlatformFilter:

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
      <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
      <version>${tycho-version}</version>
      <configuration>
        <environments>
          <environment>
            <os>linux</os>
            <ws>gtk</ws>
            <arch>x86_64</arch>
          </environment>
        </environments>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I got the same problem as Matteo and your solution works for me! :) +1

Comment: Sorry, after asking the question I had to switch on another topic... But, since this answer works for you, I'm going to accept it! :)